# Short Circuit Intersect / Inner Join feature in SQL on a condition, not field (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, intersect

I am looking for the feature to join two tables on one condition (not field) in a "short-circuit way", provided the join operation is absolutely expensive (a.field::VARCHAR is contained within extensive b.field::TEXT).

I don't need duplicates, it's more of a "get rows of *words.'word'* field which are contained in any *books.'content'* field". If the first book contains it, skip checking if the other 2000-pages books also contains it.

If I am not wrong, neither INNER JOIN nor INTERSECT are useful in my situation:

- For INTERSECT, I cannot intersect on a concrete condition like CONTAINS, so I need to retrieve all registries in both places, do the cartesian product and then filter by where
- For INNER JOIN, as it returns duplicates, I infer the logic is not short-circuit, and it will check if my word is contained in each of the Books' entries
- IN and EXISTS also seem not to work on custom conditions

Is there any way to perform my need in a optimal performant way?

Comment: I don't really understand the question (could you add some example data?), but it looks like you want a `select ... FROM a WHERE EXISTS ( ... FROM b WHERE some_conditions_involving_a_and_b)`

Comment: I did not think of that approach, yes, it could work like SELECT word FROM words WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM books WHERE content LIKE CONCAT('%'',word,'%'). Would it be performant to subquery each time?

Comment: The subquery is **not** "executed every time". And EXISTS() works for **every** condition, even pathological cases like `select * FROM a JOIN b ON exists (select 42 where random() < 0.5);`

Comment: Then it's not short-circuit logic, so it is not really the optimal approach given my needs

Comment: I mean if I understand you correctly, EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM books WHERE content LIKE CONCAT('%'',word,'%')) will check in all books even if the first one already contains the word

Comment: No, you understand me wrong. Check the output of `explain analyze your_query;` And you don't need the concat() and like() - construct.

Comment: i mean if the subquery is executed once, exists(...) is indeed exists(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)... which means the calculation of following 1's is useless. Am I right? And how can I save the LIKE and CONCAT, you mean using ||?

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM words w
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM books b
        WHERE POSITION( w.word IN b.book) > 0
        );
```